# How to check if an object is an instance of a NodeList in IE?

Tags: javascript

Why is NodeList undefined in IE6/7?

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="testform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="foobar[]" value="1" id="" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="foobar[]" value="2" id="" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="foobar[]" value="3" id="" />    
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
(function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('testform')['foobar[]']
    if (el instanceof NodeList) {
        alert("I'm a NodeList");
    }  
})();
</script>
```

This works in FF3/Safari 3.1 but doesn't work in IE6/7. Anyone have any ideas how to check if el is an instance of NodeList across all browsers?

Answer (score 15):

"[Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)" should always work:

```
...

if (typeof el.length == 'number' 
    && typeof el.item == 'function'
    && typeof el.nextNode == 'function'
    && typeof el.reset == 'function')
{
    alert("I'm a NodeList");
}
```

Comment: I was about to vote this down (extremely hacky), but after doing more research this appears to be the only way to do it in IE. +1.

Answer (score 4):

Adam Franco's answer *almost* works. Unfortunately, `typeof el.item` returns different things in different version of IE (7: string, 8: object, 9: function). So I am using his code, but I changed the line to `typeof el.item !== "undefined"` and changed `==` to `===` throughout.

```
if (typeof el.length === 'number' 
    && typeof el.item !== 'undefined'
    && typeof el.nextNode === 'function'
    && typeof el.reset === 'function')
{
    alert("I'm a NodeList");
}
```

Comment: I got here a bit late:-). There is no difference between `===` and `==` here, absolutely none other than the extra character for `===`. And the *nextNode* and *reset* properties are not part of the W3C DOM Core 3 specification for [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) so it is not a particularly good test.

Comment: There is a difference between `===` and `==`. The former, aside from being slightly faster, will compare the two values as if they are the same type. If they are not the same type (i.e., both are not strings) then it will return false. This is very important, particularly when dealing with falsy values. If you assume a variable `x` has been assigned the Boolean value `false` by some other code, but in fact it is still undefined, then `x == null` and `x == false` will return true, which is not the case.

Comment: You missed the word "here". *typeof* returns a string, which is compared to another string. The first step in both the [abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) and the [strict equality comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6) is to compare Type. If the Types are the same, the remainder of the comparison is identical. Difficult to see why one would be faster than the other **in this case**. I presume you are happy with false negatives from the *nextNode* and *reset* tests?

Comment: It's good practice to use `===` unless you have a really good reason not to. You gain nothing from using `==` when you're guaranteed the same type, like with `typeof`. As for the `nextNode` and `reset` tests, I'm not happy, but the point of this script is for testing IE(7). It's a hack. In my script, I first check for standards (which catches most browsers), then only try this script if none of those tests were supported.

Comment: @craigpatik Since when is `===` ever faster? It has to not only typecheck but also value check both sides, compared to simply equality checking both sides. Sure, if the majority of the time they AREN'T the same types, then it will be faster but most of the time they will be the same type meaning you will be wasting time doing it. I'm not saying you shouldn't use `===` I'm just saying most of the time it is slower.

Comment: @jduncanator Triple-equals is [well documented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044750/javascript-performance-difference-between-double-equals-and-triple-equals) as faster. For example, `"123" == 123` (with double-equals) returns `true`. In this case, the engine sees that the types are different, which *implies* `false`, but it then has to convert the string to a number to see if the values are actually different. Triple-equals does no additional conversions or checks — as soon as it sees different types, it returns `false` and stops evaluating.

Comment: @jduncanator Even ignoring speed, it's good practice to use triple-equals because then your code must be designed toward specific types and you're less likely to allow incorrect values to slip through. For example, if you wrote `if (myBoolean == false)` where `myBoolean` is passed from some other function, it wouldn't catch a situation where `myBoolean` was mistakenly set to `undefined`, `null`, or some other falsy value by the calling function. It can be hard to track down bugs with code like this, and later you may need `myBoolean` to be literally `false` and not some other falsy value.

Comment: @craigpatik Re being faster: Thats what I said in my post. If you mainly deal with situations where both variables are of different types, then yes it will be faster. Most of the time however it will be slower when you KNOW both variables are of the same time. Like I said, I'm not preaching against using `===`, you should use it most of the time unless you know a certain piece of code is time sensitive (eg. crypto or math) and you can be certain both sides of the operation will be the same type. Then, using a `==` will be faster than a `===`.

Comment: === / == aside, regarding "typeof el.item returns different things in different version of IE (7: string, 8: object, 9: function)"  ...is this correct? ie. is this answer actually more reliable than the answer above?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use something that always evaluates to a certain type.  Then you just do a true/false type check to see if you got a valid object.  In your case, I would get a reference to the select item like you are now, and then use its getOptions() method to get an HTMLCollection that represents the options.  This object type is very similar to a NodeList, so you should have no problem working with it.

Answer (score 0):

With **jQuery**:

```
if (1 < $(el).length) {
    alert("I'm a NodeList");
}
```