# How to detect HTMLCollection/NodeList in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure my current implementation is available all the time:

```
function isNodeList(nodes) {
    var result = Object.prototype.toString.call(nodes);
    // modern browser such as IE9 / firefox / chrome etc.
    if (result === '[object HTMLCollection]' || result === '[object NodeList]') {
        return true;
    }
    //ie 6/7/8
    if (typeof(nodes) != 'object') {
        return false;
    }
    // detect length and item 
    if (!('length' in nodes) || !('item' in nodes)) {
        return false;
    }
    // use the trick NodeList(index),all browsers support
    try {
        if (nodes(0) === null || (nodes(0) && nodes(0).tagName)) return true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A common situation is {length:1,item:function(){return [];}}
The value of result in chrome / safari / opera is '[object NodeList]'.
In firefox and IE 9 , it is '[object HTMLCollection]'.

Which is the standard value?

Comment: [How to check if an object is an instance of a NodeList in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151348/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-nodelist-in-ie)

Comment: @Matt Ball -- typeof nodes.item returns 'string' in ie6,not 'function'.so we need more detection.

Answer (score 53):

The following should return *true*, if nodes is of type **NodeList**

```
NodeList.prototype.isPrototypeOf(nodes)
```

@DavidSpector, for **HTMLCollection** you can similarly use :

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.isPrototypeOf(collection)
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question: how to tell if an object is an HTML Collection.

Comment: ES lint safe version: `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(NodeList.prototype, nodes)`

Answer (score 25):

I would structure the code differently:

```
function isNodeList(nodes) {
    var stringRepr = Object.prototype.toString.call(nodes);

    return typeof nodes === 'object' &&
        /^\[object (HTMLCollection|NodeList|Object)\]$/.test(stringRepr) &&
        (typeof nodes.length === 'number') &&
        (nodes.length === 0 || (typeof nodes[0] === "object" && nodes[0].nodeType > 0));
}
```

Notes:

- less return paths make easier-to-read code
- stick with one type of logic, if possible (i.e. use less negated checks)
- `"item"` is not mandatorily in a nodeList
- use `hasOwnProperty()` instead of `in`
- use square brackets to index into the list
- I don't think a try/catch is really necessary, but that might be wrong - you decide
- check for `nodeType` instead of `tagName`, as text nodes or comments do not have a name
- add more checks to the `&&` chain if you see fit

Comment: occasionally getting this error live: `'0.nodeType' is null or not an object` . any idea what could have slipped through?

Comment: why even have the return true/false… just return the value you're testing in the if.
i.e. remove the if statement + returns and just replace it with return.

Comment: `nodes.hasOwnProperty('length')` returning false in Chrome for me. maybe `typeof nodes.length === 'number'` is better?

Comment: @MaxGJPanas Yes, that worked at the time, but apparently things change. I've modified my answer accordingly, thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 17):

Here is how to test if an object is a NodeList in modern browsers:

```
if (nodes instanceof NodeList) {
  // It's a NodeList object
}
```

Comment: Extremely slow method by the way.

Comment: @Frondor why so?

Answer (score 13):

**script**:

```
Element.prototype.isNodeList = function() {return false;}
NodeList.prototype.isNodeList = HTMLCollection.prototype.isNodeList = function(){return true;}
```

**use like this**:

```
var d; // HTMLCollection|NodeList|Element
if(d.isNodeList()){
  /*
    it is HTMLCollection or NodeList
    write your code here
  */
}else{
  /*
    it is not HTMLCollection and NodeList
    write your code here
  */
}
```

Answer (score 11):

[Check if variable is an HTMLcollection or a dom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457816/check-if-variable-is-an-htmlcollection-or-a-dom-element)

```
  var foo = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  var foo2 = document.getElementsByClassName('divCollection');
  console.log(foo instanceof HTMLElement);
  console.log(foo instanceof HTMLCollection);
```

Comment: @Horay I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it does help!
How can I check if it's not `instanceof HTMLCollection`? Where do I put the (!) exclamation mark?

Comment: The good solution... thanks.
@Horay Probably it's too late, but... if (!(stuff instanceof That)) { ... }

Comment: It's actually `foo instanceof window.HTMLCollection` if you use the standard style - https://standardjs.com/

Answer (score 5):

This answer is probably really really late, but....

```
if (nodes == '[object NodeList]') {
  // It's a nodeList
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in IE8 though =(    You get "[object Object]"

Answer (score 1):

I created a benchmark of all answers here to see, what is the best approve in speed. Turns out `NodeList.prototype.isPrototypeOf(nodes)` is by far the fastest. But in a normal use-case `nodes instanceof NodeList` would be fine too.

I personally would just not pick the `isNodeList` function, because its slow, custom and too much overhead.

Comment: I prefer if (!!nodes.length) // true

Comment: Checking if `length` property is available has nothing in common with checking if a variable is type of `NodeList`.

Comment: Do you still have the data and can share the benchmark? If that's the case, this should probably be the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

Below is a JavaScript function to check if an HTMLCollection or NodeList exists in the DOM of a web page, and the code below was tested in the **Chrome Dev Tools > Console** tab of https://stackexchange.com/:

```
function ifElemExists(elem) {
    if((elem instanceof NodeList) || (elem instanceof HTMLCollection)) return true;

    return false;
}

const elem1 = document.querySelector('.blah');
const elem2 = document.querySelectorAll('.siteHeader');
const elem3 = document.getElementById('footer');
const elem4 = document.getElementsByClassName('blah');

console.log(ifElemExists(elem1)); // Output: false
console.log(ifElemExists(elem2)); // Output: true
console.log(ifElemExists(elem3)); // Output: false
console.log(ifElemExists(elem4)); // Output: true
```