# javascript return in IE8 - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, return

```
var result = Object.prototype.toString.call(nodes);
return (
    typeof nodes === 'object'
    &&
    /^\[object (HTMLCollection|NodeList|Object)\]$/.test(result)
    &&
    nodes.hasOwnProperty('length')
    &&
    (nodes.length == 0 || (typeof nodes[0] === "object" && nodes[0].nodeType > 0))
)
```

This works properly in Chrome, but throws error in IE8 (probably 7 too). Error is happening at `return` line.

This I stole from somewhere on here (I'll keep trying to find the link). It's supposed to determine if a given object (`nodes`) is a node list. Lots of results for this error, but none I could find for this case. Anything jump out at anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's the original article I got the test function from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238177/detect-htmlcollection-nodelist-in-javascript

Comment: Which object doesn't support which property or method?

Comment: This link may perhaps include a fix for your issue.  While not related to checking nodelists, your inclusion of the use of hasOwnProperty triggered something in my memory.  In IE8, it only works for non Host objects, but there is a work around in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157700/object-has-no-hasownproperty-method-i-e-its-undefined-ie8

Comment: @Musa: IE doesn't actually tell you.  It just says that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: If one was to use the F12 developer tools and debugged the code, you would know exactly what was causing the error.

Comment: @Cory: Using IE's "developer tools"?  I've never had luck using those to debug anything, ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @STLRick:

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nodes, 'length')`

seems to have fixed it! At least, it's not throwing an error anymore. Not 100% sure if it's affecting the node check, but it is working in the few test cases I am running!

Comment: Guess I should have posted it as an answer instead of a comment ;)  Glad it helped!