# Array.isArray() does not work on a NodeList. Is there an alternative?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I would like to determine if a variable is a <del>an array of DOM elements</del> NodeList or a single DOM element. I tried `Array.isArray(x)` but it returns false when `x = document.getElementsByClassName("test")` because it is a NodeList not an array.

Is there a <del>an alternative</del> way to do this?

The solution I came up with was to test if `typeof x.attributes == "undefined"`, presuming that all DOM elements will have an `attributes` property. Is there anything wrong with this?

sample:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var y = x[0];

console.log(Array.isArray(x));                   // returns false
console.log(typeof x.attributes == "undefined"); // returns true

console.log(Array.isArray(y));                   // returns false
console.log(typeof y.attributes == "undefined"); // returns false
```

sample html:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the HTML you're parsing?

Comment: This SO thread might help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238177/detect-htmlcollection-nodelist-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have two answers explaining, why it fails. To make it work, the way you might expect it, you could test for "array-like" objects:

**Source:** https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-7/array-like-objects

```
// Determine if o is an array-like object.
// Strings and functions have numeric length properties, but are 
// excluded by the typeof test. In client-side JavaScript, DOM text
// nodes have a numeric length property, and may need to be excluded 
// with an additional o.nodeType != 3 test.
function isArrayLike(o) {
    if (o &&                                // o is not null, undefined, etc.
        typeof o === "object" &&            // o is an object
        isFinite(o.length) &&               // o.length is a finite number
        o.length >= 0 &&                    // o.length is non-negative
        o.length===Math.floor(o.length) &&  // o.length is an integer
        o.length < 4294967296)              // o.length < 2^32
        return true;                        // Then o is array-like
    else
        return false;                       // Otherwise it is not
}
```

This basically just tests if the object has a length property that is a positive integer.

Here you can see it in action:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8Yjs/)

Another solution, that is more specific to your problem, would be to just test, if the object is an instance of `NodeList`:

```
console.log(x instanceof NodeList); // returns true
console.log(y instanceof NodeList); // returns false
```

Comment: Thanks, so far this is the only actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementsByClassName() turns back a NodeList not an Array, which is why you're getting false.

Try this in your browser console:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("header")
x.isArray() // TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'isArray'
```

Answer (score 1):

[`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an HTMLCollection, not an array:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names); // or:
elements = rootElement.getElementsByClassName(names);
```

> elements is a HTMLCollection of found elements. names is a string
>   representing the list of class names to match; class names are
>   separated by whitespace getElementsByClassName can be called on any
>   element, not only on the document. The element on which it is called
>   will be used as the root of the search.

You'd need to convert that HTMLCollection into an array first.

The [W3C spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname) also details this:

> The getElementsByClassName(classNames) method must return the list of
>   elements with class names classNames for the context object.
>
> Given the following XHTML fragment:

```
<div id="example">
    <p id="p1" class="aaa bbb"/>
    <p id="p2" class="aaa ccc"/>
    <p id="p3" class="bbb ccc"/>
</div>
```

> A call to
>   document.getElementById('example').getElementsByClassName('aaa') would
>   return a HTMLCollection with the two paragraphs p1 and p2 in it.
>
> A call to getElementsByClassName('ccc bbb') would only return one
>   node, however, namely p3. A call to
>   document.getElementById('example').getElementsByClassName('bbb  ccc ')
>   would return the same thing.
>
> A call to getElementsByClassName('aaa,bbb') would return no nodes;
>   none of the elements above are in the aaa,bbb class.
>
> The getElementById(elementId) method must return the first element, in
>   tree order, within the context object's tree, whose ID is elementId,
>   or null if there is none.