# Check if variable is an HTMLcollection or a dom element

Tags: javascript, typeof

If I have two variables

```
var foo = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var foo2 = document.getElementsByClassName('divCollection');
```

How can I check if a variable is an element, and how can I check if it is an `HTMLcollection`?

I tried using `typeof myVar`, but both variables return an `object`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238177/how-to-detect-htmlcollection-nodelist-in-javascript

Comment: @PranavCBalan If I want to check if it's an element, I should do what this answer says: http://stackoverflow.com/a/384380/5244870 And if I want to check if it's an HTMLCollection, I should do what you posted?