# How to check if a variable exist in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two variables in a jquery code and if item.a not exist, it outputs a 'null' so i want to check if the variable exists. Here's the code:

```
.append( "<a>" + item.a + ", " + item.b + "</a>" )
```

If there is no "item.a" it results in

```
null, Blabla
```

I tried this if / else statement but it returns nothing

```
.append( "<a>" + (item.a) ? item.a : + ", " + item.b + "</a>" )
```

Any idea?

Comment: Use native JavaScript, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null for more details.

Comment: strictly speaking you do not need an _existence_ check - if the value is `null` you need a _falsey_ check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt was close. Try this instead:

```
.append( "<a>" + (item.a ? item.a : "") + ", " + item.b + "</a>" )
```

Or, assuming you don't want the comma when you don't have `item.a`:

```
.append( "<a>" + (item.a ? item.a + ", " : "") + item.b + "</a>" )
```

Comment: @Alnitak - Yeah, probably. I've added that in.

Answer (score 1):

The condition operator you use

**EDIT**

```
.append( "<a>" + (item.a != null ? item.a + ", " : "") + item.b + "</a>" )
```

If variable is null

```
if(varName === null)
{
    alert("variable has null");
}
```

If variable does not exists

```
if(typeof varName === 'undefined')
{
    alert("variable not defined");
}
```

Comment: The variable isn't `undefined`; it's `null` instead, so your code won't work.

Comment: You should use triple equals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044750/javascript-performance-difference-between-double-equals-and-triple-equals