# Is equality operator (==) ANY faster then strict equality operator (===)?

Tags: javascript

**WHICH IS FASTER?**

I am wondering if there is any speed differnece at all between these, even if it is the smallest fraction.
I'm assuming the strict equality operator is a little faster because it can check for exact type and fail right away if not, before doing any other tests.  But I'm just guessing cause I don't really know exactly how the comparisons are made or what is done first.

This question doesn't say which is faster - 
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Logically `===` should be faster because it doesn't type cast

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374815/javascript-vs-operators-performance) SO which explains the question in more detail

Comment: Honestly, performance between the two doesn't matter. What matters is whether the operators perform the operation that you need to express. Most of the time `===` is appropriate, whereas sometimes `==` is appropriate.

Comment: @cmac check [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/Performance-of-vs-.html) another link. According to the tests provided by the author, the === operator is roughly 10% more efficient. He also provides a spreadsheet with the results showing his findings.

Comment: @n0m4d http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html

Comment: @cmac, there is no general answer, it depends pretty much on the actual data you feed into this specific comparison in this specific function *(instance)*, and how much the optimizer can optimize away (for this specific case and context). So this whole question is pointless, especially if you consider how tiny/irrelevant your potential gain is.