# How == works in case of 10 =="10" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When we compare **10 == "10"**. **JavaScript gives output as true**. Does that mean first operand 10 (`Number`) gets converted to "10" (`String`) or vice-versa?

Comment: Was that last sentence supposed to be a question?

Comment: Using the == operator only checks that the two values equal to one another. It totally disregards the type. The === operator checks both the type & value making it a much stricter operator

Comment: @TheSETJ I guess its not exact duplicate as OP wants to understand how `==` works

Comment: @melpomene , Yes I want to understand how == works while comparing 10 == "10" ( i.e. Number and String in this case )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the table in this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) `10 == "10"` means that the code behaves as `A === ToNumber(B)` i.e. the string gets converted to a number

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator will compare for equality **after** doing any necessary type conversions. The `===` operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type `===` will simply return `false` regardless. In our case `10 == "10"` after type conversion both sides of the comparison are equal so it returns `true`.

Comment: *After type conversion* conversion of which side to which type?

Answer (score 1):

`==` means check for values.

`===` means check for values as well as type.

so when comparing `10 =='10'`, javascript engine only checks for values, hence `true`.

`10 === '10'` would yeild `false` .
read mozilla's [equality comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

What double equals to tries to do is, it converts both operands to common datatype. It will try to convert both values into integer. If one of them is converted to int, both will be converted and output will be returned. If both fails, then string comparison will be carried out.

```js
console.log(10 == "10")
console.log(true == "true")
console.log({} == '[object Object]')
```

The reason second returns `false` is because `parseInt(true)` will return 1 and `parseInt('true')` will return `NaN`

You can read the algorithm on following link: [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly a question or not, but if it is; first I need to say your point is correct, a **implicit type conversion** happens here because == check for equality not being identical and second you may find these links useful:

[JavaScript comparison operators: Identity vs. Equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447024/javascript-comparison-operators-identity-vs-equality)

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

[JavaScript - === vs == operators performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374815/javascript-vs-operators-performance)

[Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Update: I did correct my mistake about conversion and cast, thanks to @melpomene.