# Is it more performant to use equal (===) or unequal (!==) operator?

Tags: javascript, performance, conditional-statements

If it checks each character of a string, it can break the loop before.
But I don't know how it works internally.

Example :

if(stringA === stringB)

**or**

if(!(stringA !== stringB))

Which is the most faster ?

Comment: it depends ... please add some more information, for example, the actual situation of the check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you performance test JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - === vs == operators performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374815/javascript-vs-operators-performance) Using strict equality `===` over `==` is generally recommended  (see this [list of JS best practices](https://medium.com/emblatech/javascript-concepts-best-practices-1f2295a2efbc))

Comment: `!== ` is faster than `===` if compared values have different type, in other cases they have same speed, because the is first type check then value check

Comment: Use the operator which better represents your logic, performance is not an issue in either case.

Comment: note that string comparison especialy can use instance checking as well if the strings are constant. JS engine compiles the strings used in the program in a table of constant strings and checks if thry have the same reference. So this is extremely fast instead of char-by-char matching. Of course if a string is dynamic a char-by-char matchign is used

Comment: Use the simplest one. You definitely don't want to make your code hard to read. You will care about performance when you really need it.

Comment: If there is any difference, there will never be a real, practical situation where the difference would be relevant.

Answer (score -3):

Here I did some simulations for you to see for yourself when which operation is faster than the other one. Feel free to play around with it.

```js
// ===
console.time();
console.log("1 === 1", 1 === 1);
console.timeEnd();

console.time();
console.log("1 === '1'", 1 === '1');
console.timeEnd();

// !==
console.time();
console.log("1 !== 1", 1 !== 1);
console.timeEnd();

console.time();
console.log("1 !== '1'", 1 !== '1');
console.timeEnd();
```

To sum it up roughly, `!==` is faster than `===`.

Comment: That is nowhere near sufficient as a conclusive test. You'll need to take each test hundreds or thousands of times and use the average to compensate for variability in how modern multi-tasking engines will schedule this on the CPU.

Comment: The real conclusion you can draw from this is that the first test is always the slowest, regardless of which one is first (you can see it yourself by re-arranging the tests). It makes sense since the JS engine can optimize further similar operations in the same script.