# Google BigQuery and JSON output format for String vs. Integer

Tags: google-bigquery

It appears that BigQuery always puts double quotes around values when selecting --format json even when the field is an integer field

If you run this:

```
node --eval 'console.log(JSON.stringify({a:1}));'
```

you'll see the string:

```
{"a":1}
```

(1 is an `integer` and it is displayed as an integer in the javascript object.)

We'd like the output of a query in BigQuery to be also

```
{"a":1}
```

when the field is an `integer` field

For example, with a "bqtest" file that contains:

```
a
1
```

do the following:

```
bq load --skip_leading_rows 1 --replace --project_id YOUR-PROJECT-ID nfl.jsontestinteger bqtest  a:integer
```

then

```
bq query --format json --project_id YOUR-PROJECT-ID "SELECT * FROM nfl.jsontestinteger"
```

You will see:

```
[{"a":"1"}]
```

Here's public table that you can use if you don't wish to create one:

```
bq query --format json --project_id YOUR-PROJECT-ID "SELECT * FROM [personal-real-estate:nfl.jsontestinteger]"
```

Question: Is there any way to get BigQuery to format `integers` without double quotes in json format output?

Just to confirm here's the same flow but we create the field as a `string` field

```
bq load --skip_leading_rows 1 --replace --project_id YOUR-PROJECT-ID nfl.jsonteststring bqtest  a:string

bq query --format json --project_id YOUR-PROJECT-ID "SELECT * FROM [personal-real-estate:nfl.jsonteststring]"
```

Also returns the EXACT same result:

```
[{"a":"1"}]
```

Should not the output be different for `string` and `integer` fields?

Comment: check great answer by Jordan Tigani back in September http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462987/how-to-preserve-integer-data-type-when-exporting-to-json/32468017#32468017

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Thanks very much.  I searched but did not find that particular question :)  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: And for anyone reading this look try this: node --eval 'console.log(JSON.stringify({a:111111111112345678}))'
it returns {"a":111111111112345680} which might be surprising :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preserve integer data type when exporting to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462987/how-to-preserve-integer-data-type-when-exporting-to-json)