# Extract BigQuery to Newline Delimited JSON without losing types

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, types, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

[BigQuery Export Data Docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data)

[Previous Stackoverflow Post on Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462987/how-to-preserve-integer-data-type-when-exporting-to-json?rq=1)

The `bigquery.extract_data()` function which extracts data from BigQuery into GCS does not maintain integer or float types. See below for python bigquery client library example:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference('our-gcp-project','our-bq-dataset')

configuration = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
configuration.destination_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref=dataset_ref.table('table_name'),
    destination_uri=f'gs://our-gcs-bucket/our-output-file.json',
    job_config=configuration,
    location="us-west2",
)
extract_job.result()
```

An an alternative, we loop the bigquery.rowIterator object and simply write the results to a JSON:

```
full_query = 'select * from ...' # query to get BQ table
# results_row_iter = bq.query(full_query).result() # google.bq.rowIterator
results_row_iter = bq.query(full_query) # removed .result() to avoid bringing entire query result into memory 
with open(f'ourfile.json', 'w') as f:
    for row in results_row_iter:
        f.write(json.dumps(dict(row), default=str) + '\n')
```

This *"works"*. The query is very fast, however looping the query rowIterator and writing the results line-by-line to a local `.JSON` is very slow compared to the `bigquery.extract_table` table.

Is it possible to use the python bigquery client, along with the `client.extract_table` function, while maintaining integer and float types? If not, then is it possible to speed up our for-loop which writes a local `.JSON` file? The stackoverflow post linked above seems like the main online resource addressing the question, however the question is 5 years old, and perhaps there is a better solution than both of my above code snippets?

**Edit:** I've updated the BigQuery query in my working example above to **not call** `.result()` after the query, which seems to avoid bringing the entire query result into memory, which resolves an out of memory issues I was having. There's really no reason to have `.result()` in the code above.

**Edit 2:** Suggestions in comments are okay, but are no better than our currently working for loop shown above. Our main issue is that the `client.extract_table` is **very fast**, since it's all being done over GCP network I think, and it's very frustrating that we cannot use this function because of the loss of types. We are simply trying to replicate the benefits of `client.extract_table` (the speed/performance, and the lack of a need to bring data into memory), while maintaining types. Our current `for-loop` code above maintains types, but sacrifices a lot in speed/performance...

Comment: looks like i'm out of luck per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462987/how-to-preserve-integer-data-type-when-exporting-to-json?rq=1)... curious if anyone knows if there's been any updates

Comment: Can you work around this problem by export in [Avro format?](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#avro_export_details) Or is JSON a requirement?

Comment: @StevenEnsslen the output from this export is being imported into a MongoDB cluster. The `mongoimport` command works with JSON and CSV (and TSV) but not Avro...

Comment: I am using python to query the table, and then dumping the results directly into a local `JSON` file... slower than using BigQuery --> GCS directly, but the types aren't lost

Comment: Would it be possible to parse "our-output-file.json" and convert the string data back to integers or floats before sending to mongo?

Comment: `our-output-file.json` is actually okay, has the integers and floats. The `for` loop that creates `out-output-file.json` is just very slow compared to the `client.extract_table()`

Comment: Does the `results_row_iter.to_dataframe()` also lose the types? If this doesn't lose the types, you could just do `results_row_iter.to_dataframe().to_json()`

Comment: Thanks @reverse_engineer - `results_row_iter.to_dataframe()` maintains the types, yes. So this approach would technically work, however converting the data into a pandas dataframe, just to convert it into a JSON, is **very, very slow**. I expect this would be even slower than the already working example I have in the post.

Comment: Did you actually check the performance of `to_dataframe`? I see in the python-bigquery code that it uses a conversion to arrow in there that might just be performant

Comment: I have not directly compared the two yet, no. Will come back with updates after comparing performances.

Comment: Are you open to download the file (somewhere) run a SED command and reupload the file to GCS?