# BigQuery return numeric types

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

In the following query:

```
SELECT 1.2400 AS dec, 2 AS int, 1.2e-2 AS fl
```

Why does BigQuery always string-encode these numbers?

[image]

I understanding returning the decimal/numeric type as a string, but why does it do that for integers and floats?

Comment: I am guessing that it is just a "bug" in the JSON converter for display.  It does the same thing with explicitly typed columns in tables.

Comment: meantime as fyi, `select to_json_string(t) from table t` will return `{"dec":1.24,"int":2,"fl":0.012` so I second Gordon's guess about UI bug

Comment: Does not seen an UI bug, running the same query through API and `bq` client give a similar result.

Comment: @DamiãoMartins in that case, is every scalar value in their json output string-encoded?

Comment: There is detailed explanation that can be seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32468017/14733669