# String to JSONObject conversion in Java

Tags: java, json

I need to convert

```
{"officeId":1,"clientId":97,"resourceId":97}
```

Please note that for values I don't have quotes. I have seen similar questions asked and answered, i haven't seen one that looks exactly like this one, i.e values have no quotes in the string to be converted.

Here's the original string from REST server

```
"{\"officeId\":1,\"clientId\":98,\"resourceId\":98}"
```

Comment: Try using `JSONParser`.. `JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse("{\"officeId\":1,\"clientId\":98,\"resourceId\":98}");`

Comment: I'm trying to import `JSONParser` in Android Studio but it seems like its not available for import. :-(

Comment: I was assuming that you were using "org.json" library. If you are using something else like Gson, it should be `JsonParser`. The idea behind is to let the parser take care of parsing it. It will guess the correct types.

Comment: I assumed android would contain `JSONParser`, but I couldn't import it, I'll try to check why, but in the meantime i am using `Gson`. `JsonParser` works well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error? You shouldn't be because it's valid JSON. If you quote the numbers, they're now strings instead.

See [Can JSON numbers be quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368231/can-json-numbers-be-quoted).

A regular parse will suffice:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"officeId\":1,\"clientId\":98,\"resourceId\":98}");
```

Comment: Yes I'm getting an error : `org.json.JSONException: Value {"officeId":1,"clientId":97,"resourceId":97} at body of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`