# JSON Object Access NodeJS TypeError

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I get the following object after `JSON.Parse`

`undefined`

```
{
  "request": {
    "command": "series",
    "series_id": "PET.RWTC.D"
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "series_id": "PET.RWTC.D",
      "name": "Cushing, OK WTI Spot Price FOB, Daily",
      "units": "Dollars per Barrel",
      "f": "D",
      "unitsshort": "$/bbl",
      "description": "Cushing, OK WTI Spot Price FOB",
      "copyright": "Thomson-Reuters",
      "source": "Thomson-Reuters",
      "iso3166": "USA-OK",
      "geography": "USA-OK",
      "start": "19860102",
      "end": "20161212",
      "updated": "2016-12-14T13:31:06-0500",
      "data": [
        [
          "20161212",
          52.74
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to access the "52.74" portion using `data.series[0].data[0][1]` but get the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Am I missing something?

Update - Code I am using (NodeJS 4.3)

```
var endpoint = buildEIAURL(event.request.intent.slots.OnDate.value,         event.request.intent.slots.OnDate.value)
        https.get(endpoint, (response) => {
          response.on('data', (chunk) => { body += chunk })
          response.on('end', () => {
            var stringify = JSON.stringify(body)
            var data = JSON.parse(stringify)
            console.log(data.series[0])
            var reqDate = String(new Date(event.request.intent.slots.OnDate.value))
            context.succeed(
              generateResponse(
                buildSpeechletResponse(`The price of oil on ${reqDate} is  $${data.series[0].data[0][1]}`, true),
                {}
              )
            )
          })
        })
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to do this? Accessing it works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/qdcpcd17/

Comment: `console.log(body)` ?

Comment: One thing I just noticed. So I did a console.log right after doing JSON.Parse and the object starts off undefined{then whatever I pasted} ...is that the issue ?

Comment: yes, that's why `JSON.Parse` is returning `undefined`.

Comment: is there a reason why ? the json seems to be valid

Comment: and, btw why are you `stringify`ing  the body ?

Comment: i was just looking at other sites and that was one of the solutions. so just testing.   Turns out the 52.74 value needs to be in "" for JSON.Parse to work ... is there a workaround for that ? Currently the api that Im using isnt sending that in quotes

Comment: no, that's not the issue. what is the value of `console.log(body)` ? Is it `undefined` ? If yes, then add `response.on('error', (e) => { console.log(e) })`

Comment: its undefined followed by the json object I posted above

Comment: It might be better if you did `body += (chunk ? chunk : "")` so that if, for whatever reason, `chunk` is undefined, it doesn't try to append it to `body`

Answer (score 0):

Works on my box. Note you'll need a modern browser (or node) to be able to run this code, due to the multiline syntax:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(`{
  "request": {
    "command": "series",
    "series_id": "PET.RWTC.D"
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "series_id": "PET.RWTC.D",
      "name": "Cushing, OK WTI Spot Price FOB, Daily",
      "units": "Dollars per Barrel",
      "f": "D",
      "unitsshort": "$/bbl",
      "description": "Cushing, OK WTI Spot Price FOB",
      "copyright": "Thomson-Reuters",
      "source": "Thomson-Reuters",
      "iso3166": "USA-OK",
      "geography": "USA-OK",
      "start": "19860102",
      "end": "20161212",
      "updated": "2016-12-14T13:31:06-0500",
      "data": [
        [
          "20161212",
          52.74
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}`);
console.log(data.series[0].data[0][1])
```

Comment: The issue seems to be that at least the version of JSON.Parse on AWS needs the 52.74 to be in quotes for it to work, thats why im getting undefined errors

Comment: That would be highly unusual, considering JSON has been pretty constant since its introduction. You could try running the code snippet via node on AWS and see what happens.

Comment: It gave me the same error. The way I got it to run was to add quotes around "52.74" . According to some other stackoverflow answers a double quote is required on key value pairs. Adding that fixes it......id hate to regex this

Comment: double quote is required around keys, not values, if the values are numbers, arrays, objects, true, false, or null. See http://www.json.org/ or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15368231/215552).

Comment: that is so odd then, why is json parse acting like this on aws ?