# How to correctly add not-string values to a TJSONObject?

Tags: json, delphi

Using a `TJSONObject`, I've noticed that its `AddPair` function has the following overloads:

```
function AddPair(const Pair: TJSONPair): TJSONObject; overload;
function AddPair(const Str: TJSONString; const Val: TJSONValue): TJSONObject; overload;
function AddPair(const Str: string; const Val: TJSONValue): TJSONObject; overload;
function AddPair(const Str: string; const Val: string): TJSONObject; overload;
```

In particular, I've noticed that there's no overload for adding not-string values like integers, datetimes...
Due to this reason, calling `ToString` function, every value is shown as double quoted:

> {"MyIntegerValue":"100"}

From what I've read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368259/4528159) answer, it goes against the JSON standard for not-string values.
How should a not-string value be added to a `TJSONObject`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `TJSONNumber` and the `AddPair` overload that uses `TJSONValue` to create a numeric JSON value, like so:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.JSON;

var
  JSON: TJSONObject;
begin
  JSON := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    JSON.AddPair('MyIntegerValue', TJSONNumber.Create(100));
    writeln(JSON.ToString);
    readln;
  finally
    JSON.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Outputs `{"MyIntegerValue":100}`

This is also how it's done in the codesample from [help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.AddPair).

Comment: This answer is technically correct. I would add that, at least on desktop platforms, the `TJSONNumber` object should be protected by a `try/except` block to free the object if `AddPair()` raises an exception, like a memory error (it is rare, but still possible), otherwise the object will be leaked. `number := TJSONNumber.Create(100)); try JSON.AddPair('MyIntegerValue', number); except number.Free; raise; end;`  On mobile platforms, this is not needed since ARC will handle everything for you.