# Using JSON: A way to apply a number and a string on same key-value pair?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, swagger

I need to define one nested JSON object which stores in use case 1 a key value with an integer (amount of something) and in use case 2 a key value with a string (UUID).

The goal is to analyse the data in later procedures.

I know decided to put the number into quotes and get away with implicit conversion. Which has been described here:
[Can JSON numbers be quoted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368231/can-json-numbers-be-quoted)

Example-1:

```
"kpiValue": {
   "type": "Driver",
   "value": 16 // => amount of something
}
```

Example-2

```
"kpiValue": {
   "type": "Driver",
   "value": "ident" // => UUID is handled as string
},
```

**Any thoughts on this?**

Comment: What is your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

A quoted number is a string.

You can safely do this.

NB: Don't forget to determine and type your variable property afterward.

Comment: The snap above is a nested object of two different objects and the determination is made in the upper level of the objects. I thought their might be a more convenient  :)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, are you searching for a workaround or do you want to know if it is ok to do it that way ?

Comment: Thanks! Considering that I need to analyse this JSON in later procedures.It would be more convenient to store the value as number instead of a string.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it fits your needs