# Optimizing conditionals/if blocks, what is preferable from a performance point of view?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I am writing a JS library, and there are two things that have been on my mind for quite some time though.

Consider an option:

```
var option = { bool : true } ;
```

Now, imagine I do either

```
if(option.bool) 

      or

if(option.bool === true)
```

The first case, despite knowing for sure that it's **either true or false**, I imagine is the equivalent of:

```
var tmp = options.bool;
if ( tmp !== undefined && tmp !== null && ( tmp === true || tmp ... )
```

That means that to try the **options.bool = true** it has to check both undefined and not null, before testing for true.

Therefore the latter case should be more performant. However, the latter case, takes a considerably more characters and will lead to a larger lib, if repeated many times.

But maybe my understanding is incorrect.

Right now, even if I do:

```
var bool = window.t ? true : false; 

if ( bool === true ) // I still have to check for true to 'have the optmimal version'?
```

Maybe the last case can be optimized by the compiler, but when it's a **global option** I imagine it's different?

**Please share with me your thoughts on this.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript performance difference between double equals (\`==\`) and triple equals (\`===\`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044750/javascript-performance-difference-between-double-equals-and-triple-equals)

Comment: If you're really asking about the performance difference between `if(option.bool)` and `if(option.bool === true)`, then the answer to all performance questions is to run a test that represents the environment you are specifically interesting in.  jsperf is an excellent tool for such a test.  Speculation without actual test results is often wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just want to know what my coding patterns should be. I used to have if ( object ) alot, but then I changed it to strict equality but it's been leading to quite a few more characters in total. I am not sure a simple test of that nature is going to help me figure it out, i'd like to know what good practise should be.

Comment: `if (option.bool)` is a perfectly fine practice if you either know that `option.bool` only contains `true` or `false` or if you are willing to accept any truthy value.  I see no reason to do `if (option.bool === true)` unless you think `option.bool` might have a non true/false value and you want to eliminate any other possible truthy values from your `if` statement.

Comment: Ok, got it. What about a method that might for instance return undefined, or an and object {} and do if (  tmp = method() ); If it's undefined it will fail immediately, but if not, it will check if it's a String and length > 0 .. a number and greater than zero. That's also another concern.

Comment: aside: `if ( tmp !== undefined && tmp !== null)` == `if ( tmp != null )`

Comment: stop worrying about premature optimizations, jsut write simple clean and concise code. js is loose typed, don't fret about strict compares, just roll with the punches and enjoy the brevity of your conditionals.

Comment: @dandavis thanks, it's not really premature, it's the end touch. I should probably use looser types but now I already have strict checks everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that tmp != null could replace that. that helps in one place at least :)

Comment: My POV: i always use conditionals with balanced operands (that's the proper term): the reason ? it's easier to read conditions when you know that the value is always on some side (left, rigth) and the evaluated value is on the other side. It helps me prevent errors due to bad interpretations when dealing with ! as it becomes hard to read when you have too much code. One minor simple thing that helps. Yes i lose things like isNaN() and isWhatever() which are short and concise but being explicit has never been a problem in life except when dealing with women and weight ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. It's less about coding patterns and more about logic.
In this scenario there are always 3 possibilities and you need to cater for each of them.
Ie. 1. TRUE 2. FALSE 3. undefined
If the value is undefined then do you want it to fall under the true or false clause? OR should it be catered for differently?

Another important thing to remember is that if it is undefined then it will always execute the code in the false clause. Is that what you want?

If you know that the value will always be either true or false then I suggest that you still use the syntax == true as this is more readable. Someone browsing over the code would know that you are looking for the boolean value and not testing if the field has been set.

You have to think about these 3 cases every time you have a boolean in an if statement, so there is no 1 answer for you.