# Display Specific Result First in Array ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of data that returns a list of names. I want to sort it so that a specific name ("Fav Team") is always displayed first in the list. There are two fields in the array that contains that value: homeTeamName and awayTeamName. How would I sort the list so that "Fav Team" is displayed first before all the other names? Is a ternary condition the right process of going at it?

```
    render: function() {
    var gameList = this.props.data.map(function(game) {
        var homeTeamName = game.home_team_name;
        var homeTeamScore = game.linescore.r.home;
        var awayTeamName = game.away_team_name;
        var awayTeamScore = game.linescore.r.away;

        var favTeam = homeTeamName || awayTeamName == "Fav Team" ? '':'';

        return (
            <li key={game.location} className="list-group-item">
                    <span className={parseInt(homeTeamScore, 10) > parseInt(awayTeamScore, 10) ? 'highlight':''}>
                        {homeTeamName}
                        <span className={'pull-right'}>{homeTeamScore}</span> <br />
                    </span>
                    <span className={parseInt(homeTeamScore, 10) < parseInt(awayTeamScore, 10) ? 'highlight':''}>
                        {awayTeamName}
                        <span className={'pull-right'}>{awayTeamScore}</span> <br />
                    </span>
            </li>   
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) your list before you render it, so you can so something like this:

```
render: function() {
  var gameList = this.props.data.sort(function(game) {
    return (game.homeTeamName === "Fav Team" || game.awayTeamName === "Fav Team") ? -1 : 1;
  }).map(function(game) {
    var homeTeamName = game.home_team_name;
    var homeTeamScore = game.linescore.r.home;
    var awayTeamName = game.away_team_name;
    var awayTeamScore = game.linescore.r.away;

    return (
      <li key={game.location} className="list-group-item">
        <span className={parseInt(homeTeamScore, 10) > parseInt(awayTeamScore, 10) ? 'highlight':''}>
          {homeTeamName}
          <span className={'pull-right'}>{homeTeamScore}</span> <br />
        </span>
        <span className={parseInt(homeTeamScore, 10) < parseInt(awayTeamScore, 10) ? 'highlight':''}>
          {awayTeamName}
          <span className={'pull-right'}>{awayTeamScore}</span> <br />
        </span>
      </li>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: What does the ternary condition returning 0 or 1 do in this case?

Comment: If you look at the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) docs it explains it very well. Returning 0, 1 or -1 decides how the sort method should move items around.

Comment: Is there a difference between `===` and `==`? I tried both methods and they seem to do the same thing. However, the results are putting "Fav Team" as the third option and the elements change each time I interact with it (i.e. onClick option).

Comment: I tried to change it so that the array is sorted `1 : 0` then I reversed it with the .reverse() method still no luck. The array does not change in a safari browser but, does in chrome. I cleared my cache and everything and it still is doing the same thing

Comment: For the difference between `===` and `==` checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/8044811/135133.

Comment: I have updated the answer. it should have been `-1: 1` for the sort, so that it correctly moved the items to the left or right.