# Dynamic form with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple dynamic form using pure Javascript. I have two dropdowns and want to make the second one appear only when certain options from the first one are selected

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="box1" name="num">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="box2" name="letters">
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#box1").onchange = function () {
      var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
      var value = box1.options[box1.selectedIndex].value;

      if (value = "1" || value = "2") {
          $("#box2").show();
      } else {
          $("#box2").hide();
      }
  };
</script>
```

But this is not working. How do I make this work?

Comment: You are mixing up Jquery with pure javascript.. `$("#box1").change(function(...`

Comment: `$("#box1").onchange` ??? That's not the way to bind event in jQuery...

Comment: yep, my mistake, updated title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems. First, your event should be changed to this:

```
$("#box1").on('change', function () {
```

Next, your conditional logic was using a single '=', which *assigns* the value. This should be changed to a double or triple equals, which checks for equality. See the difference here: [JavaScript performance difference between double equals (==) and triple equals (===)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044750/javascript-performance-difference-between-double-equals-and-triple-equals).

```
  if (value = "1" || value = "2") {
```

Here is the final code:

```
$("#box1").on('change', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();

  if (value === "1" || value === "2") {
      $("#box2").show();
  } else {
      $("#box2").hide();
  }
});
```

**Edit:**

Here is a link to a working demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/pt5yyuLz/

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the box is still there. By the way I put this in a $(document).ready(function(){}

Comment: I am getting a strange bug, this works if "box2" is an input instead of a select box

Comment: turns out that my bootstrap-select (for css) that I got from silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select is preventing this to work. When I took it out it works

Answer (score 0):

Use only Jquery or only JS more lisible and maintanable.

Your mistake : you have used `=` instead of `==` for a comparison

**Event** : use : `selector.change()` or `selector.on("change",...)`

Here an example with only Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".seconddrop").hide();
  
  $(".firstdrop").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()==1 || $(this).val()==2)
      $(".seconddrop").show(500);
    else
      $(".seconddrop").hide(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="firstdrop">
  <option value="0">blabla</option>
  <option value="1">show dropdown 2</option>
  <option value="2">show dropdown 2</option>
</select>

<select class="seconddrop">
  <option value="0">blabla</option>
  <option value="1">blabla</option>
  <option value="2">blabla</option>
</select>
```

Comment: $(".seconddrop").hide(); is not hiding the select on page load for some reason

Comment: @jebmarcus check if your select is good `#id` for select id and `.class` for select a class. If it doesn't work add `display:none;` in your style

Comment: This is so strange, when i add display:none directly inline in that second drop, it still does not hide on load

Comment: also can you explain what the 500 here is for?

Comment: I am getting a strange bug, this works if "box2" is an input instead of a select box

Comment: turns out that my bootstrap-select (for css) that I got from https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ is preventing this to work. When I took it out it works