# Angular Type Number is not assignable to left side of if statement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am returning a number from a php call. The console is printing the number correctly when I return the value in a subscribe function. When I try to run an if statement to act on the return I am receiving an error in my code that I don't know how to fix. I looked around, but couldn't find any answers to this problem.

This is all happening inside of a subscribe function. I can't refer to the variable accountStatus outside of the subscribe.

```
this.apiService.checkAccountStatus().subscribe((accountStatus)=>{
      console.log("user account", accountStatus);
      if(accountStatus = 0)
      {
        //account doesn't exist
        console.log("user doesn't exits.", accountStatus);
      }
      if(accountStatus = 1)
      {
        //account does exist
        console.log("user does exist.", accountStatus);
      }
    })
```

Debugging Errors I am receiving:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Account_Info'.ts(2322)
```

Account_Info is the name of the ts file I am using to access the database. In my apiService.checkAccountStatus() function this is what it looks like:

```
checkAccountStatus(){
  return this.httpClient.get<Account_Info>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/api/checkaccount.php`, {withCredentials: true});
}
```

Any advice is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.apiService.checkAccountStatus().subscribe((accountStatus:any)=>{
      console.log("user account", accountStatus);
      if(accountStatus = 0)
      {
        //account doesn't exist
        console.log("user doesn't exits.", accountStatus);
      }
      if(accountStatus = 1)
      {
        //account does exist
        console.log("user does exist.", accountStatus);
      }
    })
```

**you need to define type of accountStatus like in above code i define accountStatus:any ,use this code and let me know if it work**

Comment: Thank you. It was both your answer as well as someone else that commented. My final code was `this.apiService.checkAccountStatus().subscribe((accountStatus:any)=>{
      console.log("user account", accountStatus);
      if(accountStatus == 0)
      {
        //account doesn't exist
        console.log("user doesn't exits.", accountStatus);
      }
      if(accountStatus == 1)
      {
        //account does exist
        console.log("user does exist.", accountStatus);
      }
    })`

Comment: Ch Wajid, mazy kro    :)

Answer (score 0):

First, change type of observable.

```
checkAccountStatus(){
  return this.httpClient.get<number>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/api/checkaccount.php`, {withCredentials: true});
}
```

Then, set the type on subscriber and also, be careful, you are assigning instead of comparing.

```
this.apiService.checkAccountStatus().subscribe((accountStatus:number)=>{
      console.log("user account", accountStatus);
       if(accountStatus === 0)  // you have (accountStatus = 0)
          {
            //account doesn't exist
            console.log("user doesn't exits.", accountStatus);
          }
          if(accountStatus === 1) // you have (accountStatus = 1)
          {
            //account does exist
            console.log("user does exist.", accountStatus);
          }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. It was both your answer as well as someone else that commented. My final code was `this.apiService.checkAccountStatus().subscribe((accountStatus:any)=>{
      console.log("user account", accountStatus);
      if(accountStatus == 0)
      {
        //account doesn't exist
        console.log("user doesn't exits.", accountStatus);
      }
      if(accountStatus == 1)
      {
        //account does exist
        console.log("user does exist.", accountStatus);
      }
    })`

Comment: try, to not use type any. in this case, if you are totally sure, that the backend return a number, so change the type 

checkAccountStatus(){
  return this.httpClient.get<number>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/api/checkaccount.php`, {withCredentials: true});
}

this.apiService.checkAccountStatus().subscribe((accountStatus:number)=>{

Comment: Generally you should also really use strict equality `===` operator for comparisons.

Comment: What is the difference between strict equality and not strict? I am unfamiliar with this.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8044811/11218448

Answer (score 0):

If `Account_Info` is an interface, it, indeed, is not a number. You can log it to the console because you can log anything. You cannot check for a type `Account_Info` to be a number in TypeScript. Also in the `if` clause, you are **assigning**, not **comparing** the values. You have to use the following:

```js
//...
if(+accountStatus == 0) console.log("user doesn't exist", accountStatus)
else if(+accountStatus == 1) console.log("user does exist.", accountStatus);
//...
```

The reason for prepending a plus before `accountStatus` is that the Unary operator `+` in JavaScript attempts to convert the value that follows it to be a number. More info: [Unary Plus on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)

**N.B.: This only ever works if the value is indeed a number. Else, `+accountStatus` will be `NaN`(not a number).**